# LINQ statement using one of two parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on a LINQ statement. I have a table of cities where the records have either a `countryId` or a `stateId`. I'd like to just write the one statement and have the where clause check to see which of the two parameters is null and then select on the one that is not.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
public List<City> Cities(int? countryTypeId, int? stateTypeId)
{
    if (countryTypeId == null && stateTypeId == null) 
        return null;

    return _db.City
        .Where(x => x.StateTypeId == stateTypeId
                    && x.CountryTypeId == countryTypeId)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Description)
        .ToDTOs();
}
```

I'm pretty new to LINQ, and I know this code isn't right, just adding it for context.

Comment: This isn't a linq question, really; it's a boolean logic question: `Where(x => (!stateTypeId.HasValue || stateTypeId.Value == x.StateTypeId) && (!countryTypeId.HasValue || countryTypeId.Value == x.CountryTypeId))`. With short circuit evaluation, when `stateTypeId` has no value, that subexpression is always `true`. If both parameters are null, both subexpressions are always true and the query returns everything.

Comment: @EdPlunkett When you are dealing with LINQ to SQL/EF, I think it is fair to say it is a LINQ question - any suggested solution must have a SQL translation. (`HasValue` is translated by LINQ to SQL.)

Comment: Did you mean to check for the _parameters_ being `null` or for the database fields being `null` or both?

Answer (score 1):

If the `State` and `Country` ids are all `>0` you simply can do this, no need to check for null

```
 .Where(x => x.StateTypeId == stateTypeId.GetValueOrDefault()
                    && x.CountryTypeId == countryTypeId.GetValueOrDefault())
```

Else you need to add the condition if those nullable inputs have value or not, as mentioned in the comment

Edit: after seeing some comments, if you are looking for list of `cities` based on either of the parameters, then you should be using `||` not `&&` in your where condition

```
Where(x => (stateTypeId.HasValue && stateTypeId.Value == x.StateTypeId) 
     || (countryTypeId.HasValue && countryTypeId.Value == x.CountryTypeId))
```

Note the order matters, this code will first check if `stateTypeId` has value and if it has it'll match only the `cities` with that `stateTypeId`

Comment: It is the `x.StateTypeId` portion that is `Nullable<>`, as it is a database field.

Comment: @NetMage, it doesn't matter if it's nullable on db or not, it's the parameters he's checking. Look at the question first before giving negative on answers. And if it's nullable in db, linq can easily handle it without any validation

Comment: @EdPlunkett Not my question.

Comment: Seems obvious based on the actual text: "where the records have either a `countryId` or a `stateId`"

Comment: @NetMage Then how are you certain that those columns are nullable?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I read the question, though I will concede the rest of the paragraph makes the actual question ambiguous.

Comment: @NetMage You didn't write the question. You may have guessed right, though.

Comment: @NetMage, if the columns are nullable in db, `linq` can handle it without any null check validation, and that's not what he was asking. Thanks.

Comment: @NetMage, I see your point, I've updated the answer, the question is a bit vague

Answer (score 0):

```
_db.City.Where(c => c.CountryTypeId?.Equals(countryTypeId) ?? false 
    | c.StateTypeId?.Equals(stateTypeId) ?? false);
```

Using [null conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) - when a type Id is null use the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) to return false and fail the match - otherwise check for equality and return matching.

Note you [cannot short circuit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#nullable-boolean-logical-operators) the OR operator here!

I'm not sure if this is the case, but if one of the input parameters was always null and the entries were guaranteed to always have one property null, the following would be a cool solution:

```
_db.City.Where(c => (c.CountryTypeId ?? c.StateTypeId) == (countryTypeId ?? stateTypeId))
```

Answer (score 0):

My DBA has sufficiently beaten it into my head that ignoring parameters in a query (ex: WHERE Field = @PARAM or @PARAM IS NULL) can result in very bad things. As a result, I would encourage you to conditionally add only the parameters that you absolutely need. Fortunately, given that you are working with just two possible parameters, this is trivial.

Start with the base of your query, and then add to it.

```
var queryBase = _db.City.OrderBy(x => x.Description);

if (countryTypeId.HasValue)
{
    queryBase = queryBase.Where(x => x.CountryTypeId == countryTypeId);
}

if (stateTypeId.HasValue)
{
    queryBase = queryBase.Where(x => x.StateTypeId == stateTypeId);
}

return queryBase.ToDTOs(); // or .ToList() for a more universal outcome
```

Add whatever logic you may need if parameters are mutually exclusive, one supercedes the other, etc.